# On demand compiling the .vue files

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I am using Vue.js in a project. The back-end is on spring boot, when I make any change in the vue.js file, I build the complete build so that views are complied and the changes are reflected.

How can I make them compile on demand? as soon as I make any change it should be visible without explicitly recompiling them.

I can install nodes js which will run on port: 5000 and my web server runs on port 80. How can I point node js to the resources directory of that java project?

Comment: How are you currently compiling the vue files? You say `vue.js`, but do you actually mean `.vue` files?

Comment: @tddmonkey sorry, yes I meant .vue, i updated it already. I have build in my .json file so I compile them using `npm run build`

Comment: The vue cli tool reloads the page after every edit is saved. Have you tried using that?

Comment: @user6854465 once it is installed how it is it linked with my source code directory?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo how did you start your vue project? Because functionality that you are talking about comes from the box, usually

Comment: Run the cli tool from within the project directory and any changes to files within this directory will be picked up by a watcher which will re-compile and re-render the site in the browser without you having to do anything.